# azure devops, classic pipelines: Using parameters in custom conditions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Summary**: How to skip a task in a Azure Devops Task Group based on a parameter value, using Classic Pipelines.

Hi,

In Azure DevOps using Classic Pipelines, I have a Task Group with parameters and I want to use one of these parameters to decide if one of the tasks should be executed. I tried every format I could find but I am never able to get the parameter value when running this group.

parameter:
[image]
condition:

[image]

task group configuration:

[image]

I've tried the following notations and probably some more, but nothing worked. Either there was an error in the building process or the variable was evaluated to NULL.

> 1. not(eq(variables['parameters.CustomKey'], '-'))
> 2. not(eq(variables['CustomKey'], '-'))
> 3. not(eq('${{ variables.CustomKey }}', '-'))
> 4. not(eq('${{ parameters.CustomKey }}', '-'))

I followed what is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) but it seems most explanations are for YAML and not classic pipelines.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from my task group:

[image]

In your case, the second option is close to being true. Try to use the custom condition:

`and(succeeded(), ne(variables['CustomKey'], '-'))`

Comment: You're absolutely right, used your condition and it worked! I don't know what I was doing wrong, maybe it was the ne instead on not(eq( or maybe the and + succeeded... either way thank you!